# Laravel Bootstrap - how to use the package

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, package

I've installed the bootstrap plugin within Laravel project by composer using this cmd command:

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.0.0-alpha.3
```

but I didn't have any bootstrap files in the public folder. this structure is not found:

```
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

**how** to load bootstrap from vendor to my blade ?

**what** is the difference between downloading bootstrap files manually and installing it with composer? and how to integrate the bootstrap files in my blade any way ?

**Used**:

- Windows 10
- XAMP

Answer (score 2):

The files would be in the /vendor folder.

Since you need them in the public folder you can copy them over manually or, much preferably for any sizable project, make use of Laravel's [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir).

With Elixir you can do something similar to what you would do with Gulp: Lint, Minify, Mixing Files and Versioning, etc...

And of course you can define an input folder (/vendor) and an output folder (/public).

Comment: so what is the difference between downloading bootstrap files manually and installing it with composer? and how to integrate the bootstrap files in my blade any way ?

Comment: Composer has many benefits apart from the obvious part where all you have to do is type in a command and it does the job for you - but as always it depends on the type and size of project you're working on. For a very small project, downloading bootstrap manually into the public folder will do the trick. I'd still recommend using composer always but that's personal choice. Regarding your second question, once you have the files in your /public folder, you'll have to edit your blade template to include those files you require, most likely bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js to get started.

Comment: With laravel that would look something like this: <link href="{{URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"> (the helper function uses the public folder as base directory) and <script src="{{URL::asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>

Comment: is it possible to use bootstrap files in vendor without copying it to my public? or is it possible to use it without including it in the blade ?

Comment: You have to include it in the blade template. I can't praise Elixir/Gulp enough - it really does an amazing job. But if you really just want bootstrap to work this time, just put this in the header of your main blade file: <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> You don't even need to download bootstrap to your machine.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, really appreciate your help,, very last question.. can you link me to Elixir tutorial or sort of ?